# Why Red Hat AMQ 7.7.0.GA throws exception Invalid content was found starting with element 'broker-connections'

Tags: redhat, activemq-artemis, amq

I am trying to use the configuration element `broker-connections` in Red Hat AMQ 7.7.0.GA version, but it gives me following error. The same works with AMQ 7.8.0 development version. Also as the documentation from Artemis it says you can use this. Details can be found [here](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/amqp-broker-connections.html).

**Error**:

```
2021-04-23 08:44:29,772 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ214019: Invalid configuration: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'broker-connections'. One of '{"urn:activemq:core":system-property-prefix, "urn:activemq:core":internal-naming-prefix, "urn:activemq:core":amqp-use-core-subscription-naming, "urn:activemq:core":resolve-protocols, "urn:activemq:core":scheduled-thread-pool-max-size, "urn:activemq:core":thread-pool-max-size, "urn:activemq:core":graceful-shutdown-enabled, "urn:activemq:core":graceful-shutdown-timeout, "urn:activemq:core":security-enabled, "urn:activemq:core":security-invalidation-interval, "urn:activemq:core":journal-lock-acquisition-timeout, "urn:activemq:core":wild-card-routing-enabled, "urn:activemq:core":management-address, "urn:activemq:core":management-notification-address, "urn:activemq:core":cluster-user, "urn:activemq:core":cluster-password, "urn:activemq:core":password-codec, "urn:activemq:core":mask-password, "urn:activemq:core":log-delegate-factory-class-name, "urn:activemq:core":jmx-management-enabled, "urn:activemq:core":jmx-domain, "urn:activemq:core":jmx-use-broker-name, "urn:activemq:core":message-counter-enabled, "urn:activemq:core":message-counter-sample-period, "urn:activemq:core":message-counter-max-day-history, "urn:activemq:core":connection-ttl-override, "urn:activemq:core":connection-ttl-check-interval, "urn:activemq:core":configuration-file-refresh-period, "urn:activemq:core":async-connection-execution-enabled, "urn:activemq:core":transaction-timeout, "urn:activemq:core":transaction-timeout-scan-period, "urn:activemq:core":message-expiry-scan-period, "urn:activemq:core":message-expiry-thread-priority, "urn:activemq:core":address-queue-scan-period, "urn:activemq:core":id-cache-size, "urn:activemq:core":persist-id-cache, "urn:activemq:core":remoting-incoming-interceptors, "urn:activemq:core":remoting-outgoing-interceptors, "urn:activemq:core":persist-delivery-count-before-delivery, "urn:activemq:core":populate-validated-user, "urn:activemq:core":reject-empty-validated-user, "urn:activemq:core":connectors, "urn:activemq:core":broadcast-groups, "urn:activemq:core":discovery-groups, "urn:activemq:core":diverts, "urn:activemq:core":queues, "urn:activemq:core":bridges, "urn:activemq:core":federations, "urn:activemq:core":ha-policy, "urn:activemq:core":cluster-connections, "urn:activemq:core":grouping-handler, "urn:activemq:core":create-bindings-dir, "urn:activemq:core":page-max-concurrent-io, "urn:activemq:core":read-whole-page, "urn:activemq:core":node-manager-lock-directory, "urn:activemq:core":create-journal-dir, "urn:activemq:core":journal-buffer-size, "urn:activemq:core":journal-sync-transactional, "urn:activemq:core":journal-sync-non-transactional, "urn:activemq:core":log-journal-write-rate, "urn:activemq:core":journal-compact-percentage, "urn:activemq:core":journal-compact-min-files, "urn:activemq:core":journal-file-open-timeout, "urn:activemq:core":server-dump-interval, "urn:activemq:core":global-max-size, "urn:activemq:core":memory-warning-threshold, "urn:activemq:core":memory-measure-interval, "urn:activemq:core":store, "urn:activemq:core":security-settings, "urn:activemq:core":broker-plugins, "urn:activemq:core":metrics-plugin, "urn:activemq:core":metrics, "urn:activemq:core":address-settings, "urn:activemq:core":resource-limit-settings, "urn:activemq:core":connector-services, "urn:activemq:core":addresses, "urn:activemq:core":network-check-list, "urn:activemq:core":network-check-URL-list, "urn:activemq:core":network-check-period, "urn:activemq:core":network-check-timeout, "urn:activemq:core":network-check-NIC, "urn:activemq:core":network-check-ping-command, "urn:activemq:core":network-check-ping6-command, "urn:activemq:core":wildcard-addresses}' is expected.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203) [rt.jar:1.8.0_265]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134) [rt.jar:1.8.0_265]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396) [rt.jar:1.8.0_265]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327) [rt.jar:1.8.0_265]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284) [rt.jar:1.8.0_265]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:454) [rt.jar:1.8.0_265]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3232) [rt.jar:1.8.0_265]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1792) [rt.jar:1.8.0_265]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:742) [rt.jar:1.8.0_265]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.DOMValidatorHelper.beginNode(DOMValidatorHelper.java:277) [rt.jar:1.8.0_265]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.DOMValidatorHelper.validate(DOMValidatorHelper.java:244) [rt.jar:1.8.0_265]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.DOMValidatorHelper.validate(DOMValidatorHelper.java:190) [rt.jar:1.8.0_265]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:109) [rt.jar:1.8.0_265]
    at javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate(Validator.java:124) [rt.jar:1.8.0_265]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.XMLUtil.validate(XMLUtil.java:357) [artemis-core-client-2.13.0.redhat-00006.jar:2.13.0.redhat-00006]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.FileDeploymentManager.readConfiguration(FileDeploymentManager.java:79) [artemis-server-2.13.0.redhat-00006.jar:2.13.0.redhat-00006]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.FileBroker.start(FileBroker.java:61) [artemis-cli-2.13.0.redhat-00006.jar:2.13.0.redhat-00006]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.Run.execute(Run.java:84) [artemis-cli-2.13.0.redhat-00006.jar:2.13.0.redhat-00006]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.internalExecute(Artemis.java:153) [artemis-cli-2.13.0.redhat-00006.jar:2.13.0.redhat-00006]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:101) [artemis-cli-2.13.0.redhat-00006.jar:2.13.0.redhat-00006]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:128) [artemis-cli-2.13.0.redhat-00006.jar:2.13.0.redhat-00006]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_265]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_265]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:134) [artemis-boot.jar:2.13.0.redhat-00006]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.main(Artemis.java:50) [artemis-boot.jar:2.13.0.redhat-00006]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid configuration
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.XMLUtil.validate(XMLUtil.java:361)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.FileDeploymentManager.readConfiguration(FileDeploymentManager.java:79)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.FileBroker.start(FileBroker.java:61)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.Run.execute(Run.java:84)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.internalExecute(Artemis.java:153)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:101)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:134)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.main(Artemis.java:50)
```

**Configuration**:

I am using this in `broker.xml`:

```xml
<broker-connections>
    <amqp-connection uri="tcp://localhost:62716" name="my-broker" retry-interval="100" reconnect-attempts="-1" user="admin" password="admin123">
    </amqp-connection>
</broker-connections>
```

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help others who have this same question in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Red Hat AMQ 7.7.0 doesn't support the `broker-connections` configuration element. This is a new feature that was first introduced in AMQ 7.8.0.